# What weapon and knife skins contain random patterns?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm pretty confused about this.  The other day I unboxed a StatTrak Galil | Kami, and a regular Galil | Kami, but it seems the patterns on both of them are far different from each other.

Is this because one is StatTrak and the other is not?   Or is it just a random pattern that is decided when I unbox a gun?

In any case what weapons and knife skins contain random patterns?

Comment: Were both Galils the same quality(Factory New/Minimal Wear/Field Tested/Battle Scarred)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(All information can be found at the CS:GO Weapon Finishes Workshop Guide, which can be found [here](http://blog.counter-strike.net/workshop/finishes/index.html))

The reason you're seeing variants in your two knifes (despite them being the same skin) is due to CS:GO's randomization of skin offsets/scratches. What the game does is move the skin down/left/in any direction, thus making it look different despite being the same thing.
Another thing that gets randomized is the scratches. Depending on the quality, you'll see more scratches, but it does not dictate where these scratch marks will be as it'll be different for each gun.

If you're thinking that they're completely different weapons, it may be due to what the skin looks like after it's been shifted (ie. The bottom and top half of the <s>'butt'</s>; back handle look completely different and they look like two different patterns when looking at it... Or your eyes may just be playing tricks on you.

---

**Note:** Not all skins have skin offsets. For example:

A [MAG-7 | Irradiated Alert](http://steamcommunity.com/id/aytimothy/inventory#730_2_65128727) is a custom skinned weapon, yet the design always stays around the same place (still moves, but it's hard to see with a naked eye), while a [P250 | Contamination](http://steamcommunity.com/id/aytimothy/inventory#730_2_614448305) for example could have the entire texture moved, whereas a [MP7 | Anodized Navy](http://steamcommunity.com/id/aytimothy/inventory#730_2_191975170) would never have offsets (apart from the scratch marks) as it is a solid-color skin (same as using the paint bucket).

Remember, a variant is never a new design of a weapon it is only the difference in the skin's offset and weapon scratch locations/amounts.

Comment: So I'm wondering which skins have different variants.

Comment: No skins have multiple variants. They only have movement in the paint-job's location and the scratch-marks are in different places/amounts.